# Can I Control number of char in s:textfield tag in struts

Tags: html, jsp-tags

I want to control the number of character in a s:textfield tag  ,

I know there is property in input type like  maxlength is there something simliar in s:textfield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same property (maxlength) will also used in s:textfield tag.

Refer the struts docs below

http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11/docs/textfield.html

Comment: i just found it . sorry to bother you guys,. Thanks